# Single Page Aplication vs Service Oriented Architecture

Tags: architecture, single-page-application, soa

Is there any difference between Single Page Aplications (aka SPA), and Service Oriented Architecture (aka SOA)?

To me it looks like they both represent the same paradigm. But are they exactly the same? Is SPA part of SOA only for webpages? or am I comparing apples and oranges?

For reference: [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)

Comment: In plain words, they are not apples to apples.

Answer (score 4):

These two things are often used together, but they are referring to different parts of the architecture.

SPA is referring to the architecture of the UI, specifically the Web UI.

SOA is referring to the architecture of the back-end business layer, architecting for service reusability.

You can have a SPA without a SOA architecture (it is ugly, but you can generate HTML snippets on the back-end and send them to the front end, this is how earlier SPAs looked).

You can have a SOA architecture and not have a SPA if you separate your business logic from your presentation layer (like using web services in back of JSP or ASP.net pages).

They really go well together though, so it would be easy to conflate the two concerns.

Comment: In addition to Rob's answer I'd like to add that SOA would expose the services via some integration layer depending on your technical implementation.  It is in no way linked to the front-end.  You front-end could be anything: SPA, Windows front-end, or even a mobile front-end.  The front-end would interact with the integration layer via service calls, REST calls, or event messages depending, once again, on your technical implementation.